# How to get nearby places using the geonames API?

Tags: geonames

we are trying to get nearby locations using the geonames API, we have used /findNearbyPostalCodes and /findNearbyPlaceName and /findNearby for example but we are getting some locations like parks and hotels, instead we want to get cities and populated locations, is there any way to do this ? Thanks.